# How to download large files from secure server with angularJS without storing whole file in browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, single-sign-on

I need to allow user to download a lot of files from server secured by Oauth. The server expects to get Authorization header with value

```
'Bearer <token>'
```

The server is written in java + spring framework, and uses custom SSO authorization.

The files have upper size limit of 1GB. For other requests I use $http with header set trough $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common. After logging in the browser doesn't have the server cookie. Because of that I can't do just

```
<a ng-href="path/to/file">download</a>
```

since the server won't know I'm authorized. I also can't do something like this: http://blog.techdev.de/an-angularjs-directive-to-download-pdf-files/ since it first downloads whole file to browser. With 1GB files the browsers crash or slowdown beyond useful state. All solutions that I could find do so by downloading whole file into the browser first.